# What's the difference between "target creature" and "target creature you control"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Ok I'm confused. I have a Built to Last card, it says "Target creature gets +2/+2 until end of turn. If it's and artifact creature it gains indestructible until end of turn."

My opponents tell me that I'm not allowed to use this on my own cards, and I have to use it on my opponent cards, because it doesn't say "in my control." Is this true? My thought was that it could go on any target creature including mine, since there are other cards that say "target creature your opponent controls." Catch my drift?? Help!

Comment: A question for your friend to consider: If you could only cast that spell on an opponent's creature, why would anyone ever cast it at all? And if there's no reason to cast it, why would they even print it in the first place?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Well, they have printed One With Nothing and similar cards.  But generally speaking your point is good.

Comment: ANswers below are good. To clarify, a card that only targets a creature you control or don't control has a limitation, generally to limit the power of the card. Many blue cards have a 'cost' of returning a creature you control to its owner's hand, for example.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus [One with Nothing is bad on purpose](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/one-one-nothing-2005-06-06-0).

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Check out [this video on One With Nothing](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A_ndD-QmPJg)

Comment: If it could only target an opponent's creature, it would be worded like Blustersquall: "Tap target creature **you don’t control**." (emphasis is mine)

Answer (score 10):

You can pick anything matching the targeting condition.

If the targeting condition is "target creature", you can pick any creature. Period.

If the targeting condition is "target creature you control", you can pick any creature you control. Period.

If a characteristic (e.g. Green), status (e.g. Untapped), controller or owner isn't specified, it's not a factor. You could even pick a tapped creature for "Tap target creature" (even though it's impossible to tap a tapped creature) because the only part that's important when picking a target is "target creature". There is only one implicit limit to targeting: It's illegal for a spell or ability to target itself.<sup>[CR 114.5]</sup>

Keep in mind that there are many cards that add other limits. In particular, those with Shroud, Hexproof or Protection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80585/discussion-between-arcanist-lupus-and-ikegami).

Comment: For completeness' sake, I'm just mentioning this: "you can pick any creature" unless there are other targeting restrictions, like shroud, hexproof, or protection.

Answer (score 2):

Your opponent is wrong. If a card says "target creature", it can be any creature that is not protected from that spell. If the card says "target creature your opponent controls", *then* you must use it on one of their creatures. Likewise, if the card says "target creature you control", then you must use it on one of your  creatures.

Answer (score 0):

*Target creature* does not have any built-in restriction. You can choose any creature that is a legal target during casting.

*Target creature You control* forbids You to select creatures other than those under Your control AND they still must be a legal target!

Look for cards with Overload ability. It changes the word *target* into *each*, which makes the spell global:

*Target creature* becomes **each creature** (Your and Your opponents' creature!)

*Target creature You control* becomes **each creature You control** (Only creatures You control during cast)

They all need to be a legal target - that means they do not have abilities or conditions that prevent them to be targeted by this spell, like **Protection** or **Shroud**.

Your opponent is wrong because he probably assumes that the correct text for any target would be something like:
*Target creature You or Your opponent control* - which is unnecessary most of the time... Why most? In two-headed giant, it won't allow You to target Your friend creature if presented that way :)